# how to match the index value in LinkedList

Tags: java, linked-list

so this a part of my code containing my LinkedList. How can I find the match in my set of numbers.

```
LinkedList <Integer> mylist = new LinkedList<> ();
for(int i : 1; i<=5; i++){
 System.out.println("Process " + i + has :);
 int numINPUT = scan.nextint();
 mylist.add(numINPUT);
}
```

My desired output is:

```
 Process 1 has : 3
 Process 2 has : 4
 Process 3 has : 1
 Process 4 has : 5
 Process 5 has : 2
 Matched : Process 1 and Process 3.
```

Comment: where does these has values comes from?

Comment: Please provide some more clarification.

Comment: I'm curious. How does your code compile?

Comment: notice that index 1  has a user input of 3 and index 3 has a user input of 1. Is it possible to print this match?

Comment: How come process 1 and 3 become a match? What's your expectation? Do you want the user to insert a number and check whether that number matches with the process values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to compare all pairs of list items. If an index of one item equals the value of another one and vice versa, you have a match. Keep in mind, that Java indices start with 0, your indices start with 1.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    LinkedList <Integer> mylist = new LinkedList<> ();
    for(int i = 1; i<=5; i++){
        System.out.print("Process " + i + " has: ");
        int numINPUT = scan.nextInt();
        mylist.add(numINPUT);
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < mylist.size(); i++) {
        for(int j = i + 1; j < mylist.size(); j++) {
            int value1 = mylist.get(i);
            int value2 = mylist.get(j);
            if(value1 == (j + 1) && value2 == (i + 1)) {
                System.out.println("Matched : Process " + (i + 1) + " and Process " + (j + 1) + ".");
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A brute force thing could look like this:

```
for (int i=0; i<mylist.size(); i++) {
  int pointingToIndex = mylist.get(i);
  if (pointingToIndex > 0 && pointingToIndex < mylist.size) {
    int pointedTo = mylist.get(pointingToIndex);
    if (pointedTo == i) {
      System.out.println("match for index: " + i + " and " + pointingToIndex);
    }
  }
}
```

- you simply iterate your list; and for each index you check if the *value* on that index is another valid index
- if so, you fetch the value for that other index, and then you check for a match
- you might need some additional "marker" to avoid printing duplicates (I think my solution will print 1-3, and then 3-1 later on)
- and yes, this is not exactly printing what you ask for - but should give you enough to get going and finish your homework yourself

Besides: look into your *naming*. `mylist` says ... nothing. Why not call it `numbers` or maybe `processIDs` or something like that?